# Write in the widget a value in sharedpreferences?

Tags: android, android-widget, sharedpreferences, textview

I have a value stored in the sharedpreferences. I want take this value and display it in my widget in a textview. In my onCreate i have the state of toggle where tgpref is the value.

**This is part of code is refered at my MainActivity not Widget provider activity.**

```
ToggleButton togglebutton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
findViewById(R.id.risparmiostate);
preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);


boolean tgpref = preferences.getBoolean("tgpref", false);  //default is false
if (tgpref == true) {
 togglebutton.setChecked(true);
}
else
{
togglebutton.setChecked(false);
}
```

then when i write the what i want the toggle do, i save the value

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
           editor.putBoolean("tgpref", true); //value to save
           editor.commit();"
```

how can i take this value and port in my widget? i want write something like

```
if (tgpref == true) {
     TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.risparmiostate);
     textView.setText("Risparmio on");

    } else {
     TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.risparmiostate);
 textView.setText("Risparmio off");

}
```

but i can't use in the widget `findViewById`. How can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Widget Provider class (the one that extends [AppWidgetProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) and sets up your widget)

Retrieve and instance of [RemoteViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) like this;

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);
```

and then set any views by using methods in the [RemoteView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) class e.g. to set text view use this method;

```
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view_id, "Some text to add to the view");
```

Hopefully you already know how to access your Preferences from your code above.

Edit: One thing I forgot to mention was to put this code in the onUpdate() method of your AppWidgetProvider class.

Comment: so i have to write `if (tgpref == true) { RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text_view_id, "Risparmio on");` for example? In the onUpdate method?

Comment: yeah thats right, but obviously replace the id's to the layout and TextView with yours.

Comment: and move the remote views declaration outside of the if statement

Comment: just anothe one thing, right now my widget has a textview called `battery` (as id), in layout `widget`... in this textview i display the battery level and temperature... have i to create another textview for this information that i want display? or i can take the same id `battery`?

Comment: Unknown variable or field 'tgpref'... have i to declare it somewhere also in the widget provider?

Comment: look at my first post. that is part of code of the MainActivity not the wisget..how can i take the tgpref value from there?